# Jquery UI Datepicker not working on Jquery 2.0.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

a quick question, I have this [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/fa9Lq/) implementing jquery ui datepicker with version of jquery2.0.3, and i can't make it work. I don't know if there's an issue or am I missing something. I'm following this docs. as i code [jqueryUI datepicker tutorial](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

here's my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">


</body>
</html>
```

could anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include `jQuery` core library before `jQuery UI` in your fiddle since jQuery UI require core jQuery to work.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fa9Lq/1/)**

Comment: I included the scripts and css sir. please take a look at the external resources.

Comment: @kodewreckerm you have to include jquery-ui.js before jquery.js - see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9Fw5H/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny wait a moment, I give it a try.

Comment: @kodewrecker The order of your script is wrong. You need to include jQuery first. Check my demo, I just reverse the order of your included scripts there

Comment: @Felix wait a moment, I give it a try.

Comment: @kodewrecker else you can add jquery library in Frameworks & Extensions option instead adding jquery-2.0.3.js in external resources option in jfiddle to avoid order issues